# How can I run my fan if temp/humid > 26c, 60%?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Raspberry Pi, A2302 sensor, 5v fan

**QN** How can I request that my fan connected to GPIO 18 activates and stays active, until the temperature from my sensor at pin 5 reads either a temperature of less than 26 celcius, or a humidity of less than 60%?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.AM2302
pin = 5
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
   print('Temp={0:0.1f}*C  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
else:
   print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18, 1)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(18, 0)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide the actual code, but it seems like you just want to know the logic to use?

`do the following once every minute (or however often):
if temp< 26 
    turn off fan
elseif hum < 60
     turn off fan
else
    keep fan on`

Comment: Thank you, I understand if else functions, however I was after syntax that would specifically fit into the context of the code already written. This would not work as "do the following once every minute" hasnt been defined with any particular timing function and neither have "temp" or "hum".